# Can't apply dynamic styles to element using computed property or method

Tags: vue.js, styles, spread

Trying to use spread operator in dynamic styles (not useful in this simplified example but important in my real case with multiple style objects). In addition I need to use a method with a parameter, but it doesn't work. In fact even with a computed property it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goldorak/79wrj301/2/)

Markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="item" :style="{ ...styleComputed }">
    item
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" :style="{ ...styleMethod('red') }">
    item
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
        styleComputed: function(){
        return { 'background-color': 'red' };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    styleMethod: function(val){
        return { 'background-color': val };
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see from snippet you just forgot to reference vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    styleComputed() {
      return { 'background-color': 'red' };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    styleMethod(val) {
      return { 'background-color': val };
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="item" :style="{ ...styleComputed }">
    item
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" :style="{ ...styleMethod('blue') }">
    item2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the destructuring breaks the reactivity?

You should use the array binding instead to bind multiple objects into class / style:

```html
<div
  :style="[styledComputed, { opacity: 1 }]"
  :class="['static-class', { active: isActive }, myComputedClasses]"
>
</div>
```

Comment: I know for a fact you can use spread operator inside dynamic styles (the codebase I work on is full of it), I just don't know why it doesn't work in my case